# Bluetooth device keeps disconnecting on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

My problem is that I am connecting my Bluetooth earbuds to my computer which runs Windows 10. It runs properly and fine for a couple of minutes but then randomly it just disconnects from my computer and I have to turn it off and on to reconnect it to my computer.

I have tried turning off the power save mode option in power management but the thing is that I don't even have that option for any of the Bluetooth adapters in the device manager.

So how do I fix this?